# using visio 2007, how do I represent a trigger and a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, class, stored-procedures, uml, diagram

I have a web service class diagram, I want it to show what stored procedures a web method calls.

for now, I just use a class with a metod inside to represent a stored procedure, something like

```
storeStuff(in this, in that, out field1, out field2)
```

but this consumes tons of space, any tips?

or are there any better ways to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found this
http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html#Figure3Keys
and this
http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html#Figure5

wich visio does well, but you can't specify what the resultset is.

anyone got anything better?

Answer (score 0):

UML part of this Question: 
[image: UML representation of Stored Procedure]

Represented as a **Single Class** with Stereotype

`<<Stored Procedure>>`

.
Each Stored Procedure are viewed as operations. 
Source: SparkSystems on Stored Procedure subject: 
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/database_engineering/storedprocedureindividualclass.html

Answer (score 0):

Having no packages as for example Oracle has, I would create a class that has a list of stored procedures. I’d write down all their parameters. I know that it can consume a lot of space on diagrams but UML allows not show all that you have in the model. So you can see just list of procedures without parameters (although they are in model!), with types or as full list. Sparx EA allows it:

[image: No parameters are shown]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, how to show that a web function calls stored procedures? Again, there are more possibilities.

1. Generally show that there is a usage between web function and stored procedures.
2. Map concrete function to concrete stored procedure(s).
3. Prepare sequence diagram.

All is shown below. I would go for 1 and 3 because of better maintainability.

[image]

[image]